# image get hide behind content in mpdf8

Tags: php, css, pdf, html

I am adding image on existing pdf overlay on one box.

here is my code

```
$sign .= '<img style="height:'.$coordinates_eqv[4].'px;width:'.$coordinates_eqv[3].'px;margin-left:'.$coordinates_eqv[1].'px;margin-top:'.$coordinates_eqv[2].'px;position:relative;z-index:99" src="'.$sign_attach.'">';

$pdf->WriteHTML($sign);

$pdf->UseTemplate($import_page);

$pdf->Output($output_file,'I');
```

But the issue is when pdf creates my images goes hide behind the content it doesn't appear on box it goes hide behind the box.

Please help me out from this issue

Thanx in advanced

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding one div and gave it to z-index.

```
$sign .= '<div style="position:absolute;z-index:99"><img style="height:'.$coordinates_eqv[4].'px;width:'.$coordinates_eqv[3].'px;margin-left:'.$coordinates_eqv[1].'px;margin-top:'.$coordinates_eqv[2].'px;" src="'.$sign_attach.'"></div>';
```

Happy coding